# Why laravel deleting all data in database even though I'm already using where to get specific data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to delete a data in database, but whenever I click delete. It will delete all data in the database, not the one I want to delete.

Bellow is my table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `attendance_group_work_hour` (
  `attendance_group_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `day` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'number day of week, 1=Sunday',
  `work_hour_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `start` time NOT NULL,
  `end` time NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`attendance_group_id`,`day`,`work_hour_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `attendance_group_work_hour_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`attendance_group_id`) REFERENCES `attendance_group` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And this is my controller:

```php
public function update_work_hour(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $request_day = $request->day;
        if ($request_day == 'Monday') {
            $day = 2;
        } elseif ($request_day == 'Tuesday') {
            $day = 3;
        } elseif ($request_day == 'Wednesday') {
            $day = 4;
        } elseif ($request_day == 'Thursday') {
            $day = 5;
        } elseif ($request_day == 'Friday') {
            $day = 6;
        } elseif ($request_day == 'Saturday') {
            $day = 7;
        } elseif ($request_day == 'Sunday') {
            $day = 1;
        }

        $group_id = $request->group_id;
        $attendance_group = AttendanceGroup::where('id', $group_id)->first();
        $check = AttendanceGroupWorkHour::where('day', $day)->where('attendance_group_id', $group_id)->first();
        if ($request->work_day == 0) {
            // when this code executed, it will delete all data inside my database, not the specific one
            $check->delete(); 
            ///////////////////////////
        } elseif ($request->work_day == 1) {
            ....
```

The case is when work_day value from request is 0, it will delete the record in database.

I don't know why this is happening, I never experienced something like this before. Usually when I'm using where & first it just deleting one specific data

Comment: Maybe some tables reference `attendance_group_id` as a foreign key and have on delete cascade.

Comment: Somehow it worked (only delete one specific data) when I change the delete method using query builder
`DB::table('attendance_group_work_hour')->where('day', $day)->where('attendance_group_id', $group_id)->delete();`
I don't know why

Comment: Is the delete method overriden in the model? That's not normal behavior

Comment: how is the model supposed to identify itself uniquely? what is it supposed to do with a composite primary key (which Laravel doesn't support) ?